# How should I properly terminate a 'here string' in powershell v1.0?

Tags: powershell

I'm using powershell v1.0 and having a problem terminating a 'here string', the console remains on >> unless I do a CTRL-C at which point I lose the variable:

```
$test = @"
>> a
>> multiline
>> string
>> "@
>>
```

How should I properly terminate a 'here string' in powershell v1.0?

I've also tried single quotes '@ to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you have the @ on the wrong side of the quotation mark in your question.  I'm able to just hit the return key a couple of times after the ending "@ and it ends.

Comment: Thanks, that was it, you just have to keep hitting return, I was expecting "@ to close it immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the closing part ("@) begins the line and contains no leading spaces.